# UUID in Laravel 7.15 views doesn't show correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

just trying to change framework to Laravel 7.15.0.
I have a table with `field_id(36)` as primary and containing `UUID()` value.

In view the data shown like code below:

```
<td>{{ $value->field_id }}</td>
<td>{{ $value->bio_field}}</td>
```

The `bio_field` shown how it should be. But `field_id` doesn't.

For example :

```
 _______________________________________________________________________________
|_______value in db____________________|_______value in view____________________|
| 82251247-2515-4139-86c0-ece2f5fca120 | 82251247                               |
| b9848c43-30af-4806-ba8c-f7eaeb786510 | 0                                      |
| 9a5b3fbf-b591-4b96-b52b-ac34307b157f | 9                                      |
| 9c7c1056-8a57-4bcd-a16f-5b9b68ccccaf | 9                                      |
|______________________________________|________________________________________|
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eloquent makes the assumption that the primary key is an integer, Now In your modal

```
$incrementing = false;
```

Or by casting the field_id column to string in the $casts property of the model, like so:

```
protected $casts = [
    'field_id' => 'string'
]
```

You can get more info here https://dev.to/wilburpowery/easily-use-uuids-in-laravel-45be & https://medium.com/@steveazz/setting-up-uuids-in-laravel-5-552412db2088

Comment: `$casts` property looks good to me. Really helpful thanks man.

Comment: nice to hear that